# How can I prevent the browser from making two history entries when I link to a page with an anchor?

Tags: html, anchor, browser-history, html5-history

I am adding links to pages around my site like this:

```
<a href="/users#user_564">Name of user</a>
```

The idea is that I have a large list of users and I want to scroll the page immediately to the place where the desired user is. However, whilst this works, when the user presses the back button, they go not back to where they came from, but to the top of the `/users` page. They then have to press the back button again in order to get to the previous page.

How can I stop this weird behaviour? I have looked at the history API and it seems that it's impossible to delete an entry. Some other answers have suggested that this is the intended behaviour, but it seems very counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: 1) handle these links internally, preventing their default action, and 2) use `replaceState` method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in the Rails turbolinks gem, which I am using. Disabling turbolinks makes it work as expected.

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/pull/364